# Android Socket Chat

Tags: android, sockets

Is it possible to implement a messenger in an android application using Socket?

It must be able to:

- Establish a connection with different people (not just one)
- Send message between 2 phones
- Requires no additional set up like port forwarding (just click and message)

And does socket works that when connection is established, one phone will host the session for the other?

Comment: Yes. That's possible.

Comment: You will most likely need a third machine acting a server to relay the messages between the two devices. In some cases, direct device-to-device traffic will work. But there will be lots of cases when it won't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, also is it possible to send offline messages?

Comment: I'm not such how the server part works

Comment: @BloopieBloops: It acts just like a message board. It provides a central place both the sender and recipient can reach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try [google cloud messaging service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, is the documentation in the GCM website enough for me?